# ECS container cannot reach database

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I was able to deploy a container via ECS to my public subnet.
Launch type EC2, default bridge network.

When I attach to the running container and try to ping my database endpoint, I can't hit it.

#### database private subnet security group

Has inbound rules from public subnet as follows:

```
HTTP        TCP 80
PostgreSQL  TCP 5432
HTTPS       TCP 443
All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP    All
```

(seemingly no outbound rules tho - is that the problem)?

#### NACL

```
100    PostgreSQL (5432)    TCP (6)   5432 (from my public subnet cidr) ALLOW
*      ALL traffic DENY
```

The only thing I can think of is that the ping itself uses ICMP (right?) but it's not in the NACL. I just added it as rule 200:

```
200  Custom ICMP Rule  ICMP (1)  Echo Reply (from my public subnet cidr) ALLOW
```

but i still can't ping the db. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the  Security Group attached to your Database? It should allow connections from your EC2 instance.

Comment: @Mornor yes it already has TCP 5432 inbound from my public subnet. I'll update the question to clarify all the rules in place.

Comment: What's the SG attached to your instance? You should reference it as inbound to the SG attached to your DB.

Comment: @Mornor yes, database has only one SG attached and it is listed as `CIDR/IP - Inbound 10.x.x.x/24` which is the cidr for my public subnet where the container is running.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the Security Group to allow any network traffic to access the RDS server. In this case, you can whitelist the inbound Security Group in the RDS.

For example, if the RDS server is in Security Group 1, and the ECS server is in Security Group 2, you can enter the ID of Security Group 2 in the inbound access rule of Security Group 1.

For Troubleshooting try the below scenarios:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-task-connect-rds-database/

Thanks

Comment: as far as i can see this is what I've done. Still can't reach db. Can't ping (even though have added ICMP rules inbound on either side).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know nacl needs outbound rules as well even if your inbound rules are ok if there are no outbound rules they are denied by default in comparision to what security group does. as nacl are state less and security groups are stateful